# Trying and failing to pass a JavaScript array to my ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, devexpress

Been trying to work out why my AJAX call isn't working. I've got datagrid in which the user can select rows for deletion; pushing the delete button should then send the IDs of these selected rows as an array to my controller for processing. My controller only receives an empty array of int however.

Here is my code and if someone can see something obvious that I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated:

```
    @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
          .ID("gridDeleteSelected")
          .Text("Purge Selected")
          .Height(34)
          .Type(ButtonType.Default)
          .StylingMode(ButtonStylingMode.Outlined)
          .Width(120)
          .Disabled(true)
          .OnClick("purgeSelectedBatches")
    )
```

My relevant JavaScript (selectedLoadContexts method is called when user selects rows in datagrid):

```
<script>
var recordsToBePurged; 

function selectLoadContexts(data) {

    var purgeButton = $("#gridDeleteSelected").dxButton("instance");
    purgeButton.option("disabled", !data.selectedRowsData.length);
    recordsToBePurged = data;   

}

function purgeSelectedBatches() {

    var selectedKeys = recordsToBePurged.selectedRowKeys;
    console.log("selected keys = " + selectedKeys);

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("PurgeSelected", "Purge")",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON', 
        data: JSON.stringify({selectedKeys : selectedKeys}),
        success: function() {

            var url = '@Url.Action("PurgeSelected", "Purge")' +
                '?selectedKeys=' +
                selectedKeys;
            window.location = url;
        }
    }).done(function() {
        DevExpress.ui.notify("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain: ", "info", 1500);
        console.log("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain");
    });

}

</script>
```

My controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult PurgeSelected(int[] selectedKeys)
    {
        
        //process array of keys and remove selected records

        return Ok($" records removed");
    }
```

[image: Console image added]
[image: Network image added]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the recordsToBePurged.selectedRowKeys is a comma seperated string and not an array. In order for this to work you need to convert the string to an integer array before passing it to PurgeSelected method of PurgeController. So your code will be something like

```
function purgeSelectedBatches() {

    var selectedKeys = recordsToBePurged.selectedRowKeys;
    console.log("selected keys = " + selectedKeys);
    //convert the coma seperated value to an int[] before
    var selectedKeysAsArray = selectedKeys.split(',');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("PurgeSelected", "Purge")",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'JSON', 
        //pass the values as an array and not as string
        data: JSON.stringify({selectedKeys : selectedKeysAsArray }),
        success: function() {

            var url = '@Url.Action("PurgeSelected", "Purge")' +
                '?selectedKeys=' +
                selectedKeys;
            window.location = url;
        }
    }).done(function() {
        DevExpress.ui.notify("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain: ", "info", 1500);
        console.log("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain");
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but i get a console error "Uncaught TypeError: selectedKeys.split is not a function" which leads me to believe it's not a comma seperated string (apologies, my JS is extremely limited though).

Comment: Hi, try it like this as there was an unnecessary space before split: var selectedKeysAsArray = selectedKeys.split(','); If this doesn't work then this error is about selectedKeys not being a string and we need to know its type before suggesting anything more.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is an array of int. I added the line:        

 console.log("first key selected is: " + selectedKeys[0]);

And got this on the console: 

first key selected is: 2

Answer (score 0):

OK so I amended my purgeSelectedBatches method, stripping down the AJAX call as follows:

```
function purgeSelectedBatches() {

    var selectedKeys = recordsToBePurged.selectedRowKeys;
    console.log("selected keys = " + selectedKeys);

    if (selectedKeys.length() > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("PurgeSelected", "Purge")",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { selectedKeys: selectedKeys }

        }).done(function() {
            DevExpress.ui.notify("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain: ", "info", 1500);
            console.log("Purging selected batches marked as Do Not Retain");
        });
    } else {
        DevExpress.ui.notify("No records to be purged", "info", 1500);
    }
}
```

I removed contentType and JSON.stringify from data. Array of ints is now received by the controller as parameter containing the keys of the selected rows as expected.